# How to plot an anomaly in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given `monthly` data for `three SITES`and `three years` I would like to create an anolay plot like the one shown at [this site](http://lenkiefer.com/2017/12/11/plotting-u-s-macroeconomic-trends-with-fred-and-r/) . Data are available for the months of `Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb and Mar` only.

Data for each `SITE` should appear on a seperate panel as implemented in this code:

```
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill = "darkmagenta")+
  facet_wrap(~Station.Name)+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,9),breaks = seq(-1,9, by = 1))+ylab("Surface temperature anomaly (°C)") + xlab("Time (year)")
```

I would like to implement the following on the plot:

1. The *x-axis* labels for each *SITE* should be *month Year* format, e.g. Nov 2014, Dec 2014 etc.
2. Each month is plotted as a bar graph
3. Make the `0` line bold
4. Values above 0 are colored **red** and values below zero are colored **blue**

Below is sample data:

```
Data=structure(list(Station.Name = c("SITE A", "SITE A", "SITE A", 
"SITE A", "SITE A", "SITE A", "SITE A", "SITE A", "SITE A", "SITE A", 
"SITE B", "SITE B", "SITE B", "SITE B", "SITE B", "SITE B", "SITE B", 
"SITE B", "SITE B", "SITE B", "SITE C", "SITE C", "SITE C", "SITE C", 
"SITE C", "SITE C", "SITE C", "SITE C", "SITE C", "SITE C"), 
    Month = c("Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Nov", "Dec", 
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Nov", 
    "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
    "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), Year = c(2014L, 2014L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L), Tm_Normals_Diff = c(-2.3, 0.9, 1.4, -0.2, 2.3, 3.5, 
    1.8, 5.3, 3, 4.5, 0.6, 1.6, 1.8, 1.7, 2.9, 3.7, -0.1, 7.4, 
    3.2, 4.6, 4.2, 2.7, 3.5, 5.4, 5.1, 6.7, 0.7, 8.5, 4, 4.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Data <- Data %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(paste("01", Month, Year, sep="-")), 
         month = zoo::as.yearmon(date),
         month_fac = factor(1:n(), labels=as.character(month)), 
         col = factor(ifelse(Tm_Normals_Diff > 0, 2, 1)))

ggplot(Data, aes(x=month_fac, y=Tm_Normals_Diff, fill=col)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend=FALSE)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~Station.Name)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,9),breaks = seq(-1,9, by = 1))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) + 
  ylab("Surface temperature anomaly (°C)") + 
  xlab("Time (year)")
```

[image]

Comment: this looks awesome. Thanks a lot. How can I arrange the x-axis in ascending order? Nov 2014, Dec 2014 etc

Comment: @code123 I updated the answer to impose the right ordering.